# Как посчитать процент и вывести поля из двух таблиц

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть две таблицы **Project** и **Job**. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
**Необходимо:** вывести в процентном соотношении колличество вакансий в каждом проекте по убыванию. 
**Результат вывода:** 
id_project(из таб.2) | Name (из таб.1) | % вакансий по проекту к базе

Написал как посчитать процент:

```
SELECT id_project, 
       COUNT (position) * 100 / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM job) AS 'Procent' 
  FROM job GROUP BY id_project ;
```

Сделал связь `project.id = job.id_project`.
И застрял, не знаю как синтаксически правильно и лаконично:

1. вывести значение Procent в формате 25.0 (а не 25.0000)
2. cортировать по убыванию
3. добавить поле `name` из табл `project`.

Comment: 1. `round(вычисление-процента, 1)` 2. добавить в конец запроса `order by Procent desc`. 3. добавить join с таблицей Project.

Comment: Нафига подзапрос в выражении? Вынесите его во FROM.

Comment: @Mike 1. ROUND не помог решить вопрос, подозреваю что нужно добавить число "2" но пока не пойму в какую часть. 2. упорядочил 3. С упортребеленим JOIN - проблемы.
SELECT id_project, ROUND(COUNT (position) * 100) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM job)
AS 'Procent' FROM job
GROUP BY id_project JOIN job ON job.id = project.name  ;  Не работает. Будьте добры, поправьте

Comment: @Akina Могли бы вы более предметно объяснить?

Comment: join пишется до group by

Comment: @Mike благодарю

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT project.id, project.name, ROUND(COUNT(job.position)*100/cnt.cnt,1) Percent
FROM project, job, (SELECT COUNT(*) cnt FROM job) cnt
WHERE job.id_project = project.id
GROUP BY project.id /* , project.name */
ORDER BY Percent DESC;
```

Предполагается, что project.name - первичный ключ таблицы.

Comment: Лихо! С псевдонимами я еще не знаком, буду разбираться. 
Спасибо Вам огромное!

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT JOB.ID_PROJECT,
         ROUND(COUNT(POSITION_JOB) * 100 / (SELECT COUNT(*)
             FROM JOB), 1) PERCENT_PROJECT,
         P.NAME_PROJECT
    FROM JOB 
      LEFT JOIN PROJECTS P
        ON JOB.ID_PROJECT = P.ID_PROJECT
    WHERE ACTIVE_PROJECT = 1
    GROUP BY JOB.ID_PROJECT, P.NAME_PROJECT
    ORDER BY PERCENT_PROJECT DESC;
```